# angular5 material can't show any data in table

Tags: angular-material, angular5

Here is my angular project configuration,

```
"@angular/cdk": "^5.2.0",
"@angular/common": "~5.2.6",
"@angular/compiler": "~5.2.6",
"@angular/core": "~5.2.6",
"@angular/forms": "~5.2.6",
"@angular/http": "~5.2.6",
"@angular/material": "^5.2.0"
```

I am using angular material to build a table of data, I am following the https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples example, the code is almost the same with the exmaple, but the table just doesn't show any thing.

Here is the code:

ts code

```
export class ordersComponent {

  displayedColumns =['position', 'name', 'weight', 'symbol'];

  //dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<PeriodicElement>(ELEMENT_DATA);
  dataSource = ELEMENT_DATA;

}

export interface PeriodicElement {
  name: string;
  position: number;
  weight: number;
  symbol: string;
}

const ELEMENT_DATA : PeriodicElement[]= [
   {position: 1, name: 'Hydrogen', weight: 1.0079, symbol: 'H'},
   {position: 2, name: 'Helium', weight: 4.0026, symbol: 'He'},
   {position: 3, name: 'Li: PeriodicElement[]thium', weight: 6.941, symbol: 'Li'},
   {position: 4, name: 'Beryllium', weight: 9.0122, symbol: 'Be'}
 ];
```

The html code is

```
 <div class="mat-elevation-z8">
   <mat-table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">

     <ng-container matColumnDef="position">
       <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> No. </th>
       <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">  </td>
     </ng-container>
     <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
       <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </th>
       <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">  </td>
     </ng-container>
     <ng-container matColumnDef="weight">
       <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Weight </th>
       <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">  </td>
     </ng-container>
     <ng-container matColumnDef="symbol">
       <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Symbol </th>
       <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.symbol}} </td>
     </ng-container>

     <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
     <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
   </mat-table>

 </div>
```

I have looked into the html, found the html has produced 4 exact table html elements, but why it just doens't show any data on each html element?

[image]

[image: the final result]

Answer (score 0):

Don't go with complicated solution. Instead of that create a instance of  "MatTableDataSource" and in MatTableDataSource having 'data' is the property so, you can directly assign the array to this.

I added a demo here [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-paacbj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: I tried this as well, it shows nothing although no errors are on the console